# Future Value (FV) how to return sum from entire period NOT just Nper value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

1500 is present value with a 3% yearly increase. This means that 1500 has increased to 1738,91 in year 5 `=FV(0,03/1;5*1;0;-1500)`

Instead of returning the value in year 5 (1738,91) I want to return the sum of all the values from the entire period (present+y1+y2+y3+y4+y5) =9.702,61

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(FV(3%,5,-1500,0,1))+1500
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks

Comment: The ``SUMPRODUCT`` is not necessary. ``=FV( 3%, 5, -1500, 0, 1 ) + 1500`` works just fine.